# Python flask 'generating urls'?

Tags: python, flask

I'm pretty new to flask any web development in general. So I was wondering how you generate a link. as in, when somene registers on your website you create a link like site.com/leak1953 and that would be their profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Variable Rules

To add variable parts to a URL you can mark these special sections as . Such a part is then passed as a keyword argument to your function. Optionally a converter can be used by specifying a rule with `<converter:variable_name>`.

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def show_user_profile(username):
    # show the user profile for that user
    return 'User %s' % username

@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def show_post(post_id):
    # show the post with the given id, the id is an integer
    return 'Post %d' % post_id
```

source: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rules

Answer (score 2):

For generating links there exists the function [`flask.url_for()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for) which generates a URL given the endpoint with a method provided. You can use this function also in JINJA2 templates. To provide an external link use

```
{{ url_for('index.main', _external=True) }}
```

If you want to include parameters to the url just add them to the url_for parameters.

```
{{ url_for(show_user_profile, username='Klaus') }}
```